# Unexpected use of reserved word 'let' in strict mode

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm getting an error when I test the following code in Safari.

```
var temp_color = null;
    var temp = 0;
    var tempv = 0;
    for (let x in colorblock) {
        temp_color = colorblock;
        tempv = Math.pow((color.r - temp_color.r), 2) + Math.pow((color.g - temp_color.g), 2) + Math.pow((color.b - temp_color.b), 2);
        if (x === 0) {
            temp = tempv;
```

Safari throws the error "Unexpected use of reserved word 'let' in strict mode" but it does work when I use Chrome.

Comment: Which version of Safari are you using? This might be a browser incompatibility issue with ECMA Script.

Comment: Safari has some rather lacking support for ES2015, but you're not using this in production without a transpiler, are you ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`let` is not supported in Safari 9 or iOS Safari 9.2:

http://caniuse.com/#search=let